# adding a record to SQLite cause extra random records to be added

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am writing an application with iOS and SQLite database.
I have a tableView that displays a **list of workshops** with information i.e:Title, presenters'  names. when the user clicks **Add** button a new view is presented modally. the new view contains a **list of names**. The user can choose the workshop presenters by *tabbing on some names from this list, and then the selected name get a checkmark* besides them. after user clicks save the *records are added to the Database correctly* and the view is dismissed. 
**However**, after I **return** to the view with the **list of workshops** I find that the newly added workshop has **more presenters than I actually added**.
 When I check the **database** file I find that the *extra records* are actually added in the database which means that it is not a semantic error in the code that causes the extra names to be added.
Also, I debugged my code where the insert query is placed. It explicitly states that only the checked names are added to the database, and I NSLog the result of the query, it *prints out the selected names only*.
I don't know where exactly the extra names are added. I tried to find a pattern but every time different names are being added as extra in the database.
The odd thing is that this problem does not occur always.

UPDATE:
here is a snippet of my code in the Database.m file. I am assuming that I **added two presenters** to the workshop form my addWorkshop view controller

```
-(void)addWorksopWithTitle:(NSString *)title presenters:(NSMutableArray *)presenters date:(NSDate *)date time:(NSString *)time bld:(NSString *)bld floor:(int)floor room:(NSString *)room manadatory:(BOOL)manadatory
{
    [self openConnection];
    const char *SqlStatement = "insert into Workshop (wid,title,manadatory,date,time,bld,floor,room,wsdate,dateD) values(null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    //end of edited code
    sqlite3_stmt *compileStatement1;
    int success;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, SqlStatement, -1, &compileStatement1, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"insert WS prepair");
        sqlite3_bind_text(compileStatement1, 1, [title UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int(compileStatement1, 2, manadatory);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compileStatement1, 3, [@"Feb 15, 2014" UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compileStatement1, 4, [time UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compileStatement1, 5, [bld UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int(compileStatement1, 6, floor);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compileStatement1, 7, [room UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_double(compileStatement1, 8, [date timeIntervalSince1970]);
        sqlite3_bind_double(compileStatement1, 9, [date timeIntervalSince1970]);

        success = sqlite3_step(compileStatement1);
        NSLog(@"sucess insert ws msg:%d",success);

    }else
    {
        NSLog(@"insert WS NOT success");
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'. ", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compileStatement1);
    if (success == SQLITE_ERROR)
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to insert into the database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }


    //get the last inserted workshop id
    int wid = (int) sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    //NSLog statement to get the number of presenters to be added. it returns 2
    NSLog(@"#presenters to add: %lu",(unsigned long)[presenters count]); 
//insert presenters in Present table

    for (Faculty *presenter in presenters) {

        const char *SqlStatement2 = "insert into Presents(pid,wid,fid) values(null,?,?)";
        sqlite3_stmt *compileStatement2;
        int success2;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, SqlStatement2, -1, &compileStatement2, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_int(compileStatement2, 1, wid);
            sqlite3_bind_int(compileStatement2, 2, [presenter fid]);
            success2 = sqlite3_step(compileStatement2);
            NSLog(@"insert to present,sucess msg:%d",success2); //success message prints 101. which according to SQLite documentation means the sqlite3_step() has finished executing
        }else
        {
            NSLog(@"insert to present NOT success");
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compileStatement2);

        if (success2 == SQLITE_CONSTRAINT)
        {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to insert into the database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }


    }
    [self closeConnection];

}
```

this code add *extra* records only **sometimes**

Comment: No way anyone can help you without seeing the code you're referring to. That being said, follow the sequence. If you're getting correct results on your log but incorrect saved results in your database, it's got to be something happening between those two points.

Comment: My first question would be are you using bound queries or are you trying to build query strings Little Bobby Tables style? Because if it's the latter, you're probably getting multiple insertions because of single quotes and other special characters.

Comment: I have updated my question a week a go. Please, by too kind to have a look at it.